# 'Before or After' in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like a single word to ask someone whether something happened 'before or after' whatever it is we're talking about.

*Occurring* comes to mind but then you always say, *did this occur before or after that?*

*When* is too descriptive and asks for a specific time.

Comment: So you are after a single word meaning "temporal direction" rather than "not at the same time"?

Comment: "temporal direction". Whether or not something was hitherto or after the fact.

Comment: What's wrong with "Did thing A occur before thing B or after it?"

Comment: @HotLicks That uses even more words. I seek something along the lines of:  *Oh, yea? Was that before or after you [snarky comment].*

Comment: Did it happen subsequently?

Comment: Are you looking for a word that specifies a temporal sequence or one that means "not simultaneous"? That is, when you ask, "[word that means] before or after", are you expecting an answer of one of them (before / after), or "yes"?

Comment: @Lawrence - applicable answers are *before, after* and *simultaneously*. "Sequence" is a good one...

Answer (score 4):

*Order* or *chronology* are around the mark.

> The events occurred in what *order* ?
>
> What was the *chronology* of the events?

But the answer might not be "A was before/after...", but rather "first A, then..."

Answer (score 1):

**Nonconcurrent** antonym of *[concurrent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/concurrent)*: occurring or existing simultaneously or side by side

**[Asynchronous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asynchronous?s=t)**: not occurring at the same time.

Then it becomes general reference:

**[Allochronic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/allochronic)** used in biology to describe life forms lining in different geologic times.

Comment: these are great words but how would you use them to say: "Was that before or after you read that?"

Comment: I wouldn't use it in that context, but if I did and needed a single word, I would more likely ask "Was that concurrent with your having read that?" The answer might be "It was not concurrent." A report might say "He told me it was *nonconcurrent* with his reading that." In another context, you could say "The processor performs these tasks asynchronously. They are nonconcurrent tasks."

Comment: I think you are looking for 'when'

Comment: 'when' implies I want the specific date as opposed to just wanting to know its place in the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

**Relate** might be appropriate here.

> And, how does this change in attitude relate to your having read *Eat, Pray, Love*?

While it doesn't exclusively apply to the temporal relationship, it should elicit the answer you require without having to add in "before or after".

Similarly, **correspond**.

You can cure the ambiguity by adding the word **temporally**.

> How does this change relate temporally to your having read . . .

But, I think it sounds clunky, and is likely unnecessary unless you need to make it absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Informally, Did it happen "pre- or post-" the big game ?  I think in this case the prefixes together to form an idiom. Not one word, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were looking for something like "**approximately** when" so they can give you an approximate chronology.

> From the Oxford dictionary
>
> **[approximate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/approximate)**: - (as an adjective) Close to the actual, but not completely accurate or exact.
>
> -(verb with object) Estimate or calculate a quantity fairly accurately

The other option I have would be to refer to this as **Janus**. "Was this **janus** (before and/or after) to reading of X".
Janus was a Roman god of many contradicting things and transitions. Typically things are said to be janus if they are antonyms or are ambivalent. However Janus also represented the perception of past and future as well as the transition from one to the other so it would also fit in this context, although virtually no one would know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

**[further](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/further)** can give this meaning depending on how you use it in a sentence, though it is usually used either to mean before or after, not both of them.

> **2** past a certain point
>
> > **b.** used when saying how long before or after a particular time something is

There is "**no further than**" usage also.

Answer (score 0):

How about "When did ___ happen **relative to** _____?"

Not quite "one word", but closer...

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the [sequence (noun definitions 1 and 2)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sequence) or [order (noun definition 4)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/order) in which the events occurred.