# Is there a word for “near in time” (both past & future) that doesn’t also imply geographical proximity?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, time

I’m currently writing a program that finds the “nearest sensible job”, in terms of time. The only problem is that that phrase could also mean that the program is finding the nearest geographical job.

Is there a concise way of referring to the nearest job in time? For example, I’m looking to replace the word *nearest* in a sentence like:

> The nearest job to 12:45 was the run at 12:40. The next-nearest was the run at 12:55.

The nearest sensible job is five minutes away from the target time; the next nearest is ten minutes away in the other direction. Even there, it seems to be necessary to use spatial terms!

To clarify, I’m looking at both the past and the future, otherwise something like *soonest* would be perfect.

Comment: *Soonest*? ASAP?

Comment: Doesn't soonest mean in the future? I'll edit to clarify

Comment: You're looking for jobs in the past? Unlike spatial dimensions (geography), time is asymmetrical.

Comment: Both the past and the future :)

Comment: So you want to replace *nearest* in a sentence like "The nearest job to 12:45 was the run at 12:40. The next-nearest was the run at 12:55."

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I mean, "nearest" *works*, but I'm wondering if there's a more accurate word for it.

Comment: The first part to show the defect was produced at 12:47.53 on April 8, 2017. *Sequential* parts all showed a similar flaw.

Comment: Coincidentally I had to use this meaning in an email the other day, to describe that the second event occurred at roughly the same, but not exactly the same, time as the first event and I wanted a quick way of saying it. I used "temporally colocated", though it was somewhat tongue in cheek as the person I was addressing I know to love such geeky language...

Comment: @MarvMills If you're going to get into temporal, you might as well use 'roughly **cotemporal**'. Sounds kind of Science-Fictiony though.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I never thought of "cotemporal" but I love it and I am going to make every effort to use it henceforth!

Comment: *Contemporaneous*

Comment: Ooh, that's a good one!

Comment: ['Before and After'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157678/before-or-after-in-one-word) has no single word replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain if the proximity to the target is in the future or in the past. If it's in either direction, I would try ***closest*** instead of ***nearest***.

Come to think of it, perhaps the proximity is related to duration, in which case I would still suggest ***closest***.